# How to hide index.php from Url by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

With respect to Code Igniter And MySql:
How to hide index.php from Url by htaccess?

Comment: It has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: duplicate a hundred times over!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [CodeIgniter Manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

In your document root, a `.htaccess` file containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt) # these are examples,
                                                 # add everything here that
                                                 # you **don't** want to be
                                                 # routed to CI
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then in `application/config/config.php` change:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```